# Is there a way to avoid to prefix every predicate of a module in the SWI-Prolog console?

Tags: module, prolog, swi-prolog

Here is an example:

```
%% file named: p.pl
:- module(p,[   ]).
:- use_module(library(chr)).
:- chr_constraint red, blue, yellow, orange, purple, green.
red, blue <=> purple.
red, yellow <=> orange.
blue, yellow <=> green.
```

In the SWI-Prolog console I have to type for example:

```
p:red.
```

I know that everything is callable if I export it in the module declaration, but for debugging purposes, this is too much typing.

```
[p].
```

does not work.

What I would like to do temporarily for debugging is:

```
:- module(p,[ * everything  ]).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible alternative is to use the `module/1` built-in predicate to switch the default working module for the interactive top level. Try:

```
?- module(p).
```

After this query you should be able to call any predicate in the `p` module without having to use the `p:` prefix.

Comment: Same hold for SICStus, YAP.

Comment: I consult a module file foobar:
`[foobar].`
and this seems to get added to a module named `plunit_foobar`.
Why the heck does it do that, and how can I stop it?